# Cannot bind socket error for squid proxy

Tags: proxy, squid, http-proxy

I set up a squid proxy inside a docker-machine using the datadog/squid image, when I access the cache.log file inside the container I see the following at the end of the logs:

```
2017/11/06 21:45:10| HTCP Disabled.
2017/11/06 21:45:10| commBind: Cannot bind socket FD 13 to [::1]: (99) Cannot assign requested address
2017/11/06 21:45:10| commBind: Cannot bind socket FD 14 to [::1]: (99) Cannot assign requested address
2017/11/06 21:45:10| ERROR: Failed to create helper child read FD: UDP[::1]
2017/11/06 21:45:10| Squid plugin modules loaded: 0
2017/11/06 21:45:10| Adaptation support is off.
2017/11/06 21:45:10| Accepting HTTP Socket connections at local=[::]:3128 remote=[::] FD 12 flags=9
```

I'm not sure what exactly the commBind errors are originating from, what should I be looking into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Squid is trying to bind to sockets on localhost using IPv6 (::1).

According to [Docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/ipv6/), Docker containers aren't configured to support IPv6 by default, however you can enable it with the `--ipv6` flag.

If your use case doesn't require IPv6, you can ignore this error if Squid is otherwise working. Otherwise you can use the above Docker flag or review your Squid configuration.